# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined when imported from parent folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, import

When I'm trying to import a class from the parent folder, which is exported in an index-file, I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

When I'm importing it in other places, there is no problem.

Import: `import { BaseComponent } from '../';`

Index-file in parent folder:

```
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';
import Header from './Header';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';

export { BaseComponent, Header, NavigationBar };
```

Import in other file: `import { BaseComponent, NavigationBar, Header } from './common';`

Why does the import not work when it's in a child folder?

**UPDATE**

File structure:

```
common/
    BaseComponent/
        index.js
    Header/
        index.js
    NavigationBar/
        index.js (import not working for BaseComponent)
    index.js (export file)
App.js (correct import)
```

**UPDATE 2**

This import does work, but I'm trying to use index files to combine the classes: `import BaseComponent from "../BaseComponent";`

**UPDATE 3**

[image: Screenshot error]

Comment: The import paths might be wrong. Please verify

Comment: What tool are you using to bundle/resolve your imports? Webpack?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I added the file structure of the project

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert it's a default project with create-react-app

Comment: I added the runtime error

Comment: while creating navigationBar component did you import the BaseComponent

Comment: Yes I did import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for future reference**

I solved this problem by exporting the classes in the index file more directly. I have no clue why the original idea won't work, but this solution does the trick:

```
export {default as BaseComponent} from './BaseComponent';
export {default as Header} from './Header';
export {default as NavigationBar} from './NavigationBar';
```

Answer (score 2):

@Olivier

You are mixing default export syntax and named export syntax.

You need to match import and export syntax, so:

```
export default BaseComponent { ...
       ^^^^^^^ => export default...

matches

import BaseComponent from '../BaseComponent'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ==> import witout {}
```

and

```
export BaseComponent { ...
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  => named export
matches

import { BaseComponent } from '../BaseComponent'
      ^^              ^^ ==> use {} to named imports!
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, I know the way of importing and exporting. It was more about importing items and exporting them again in the same file.